# After integrating Struts Core 1.3.10 - Tomcat 8.0.21 server at localhost fails to start

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, struts-1

I had a simple Dynamic Web App project that would run on my Tomcat 8 server just fine. But as soon as I tried to implement Struts 1.3.10 I haven't been able to even start Tomcat. I get the error: server tomcat v8.0 server at localhost failed to start. I am using Eclipse Luna.

I originally had two servlets declared in the web.xml, but I removed them because I read that it might be a problem with overlapping url-patterns. It still gives the same error.

Here is the stack trace:

```
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MY_APP' did not find a matching property.
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.21
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Mar 23 2015 14:11:21 UTC
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.21.0
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_40-b26
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.21
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.21
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\endorsed
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;.
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1066 ms
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 13, 2015 1:01:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.21
May 13, 2015 1:01:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MY_APP]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MY_APP]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/RuleSet
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:132)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5065)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.RuleSet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    ... 20 more

May 13, 2015 1:01:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

May 13, 2015 1:01:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

May 13, 2015 1:01:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 13, 2015 1:01:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
May 13, 2015 1:01:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
May 13, 2015 1:01:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 13, 2015 1:01:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:302)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:473)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:818)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

May 13, 2015 1:01:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
May 13, 2015 1:01:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:302)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:473)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:818)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Here is my current web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MY_APP</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>consumFunctions</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/functions.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>scheduleFunctions</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/schedule.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
  </jsp-config>
  <error-page>
    <location>/errorPage.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errorPage.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>429</error-code>
    <location>/errorPage.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.NullPointerException</exception-type>
    <location>/login.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

I don't know if it's relevant, but since this the first one I've ever made, here is the struts-config.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC 
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN" 
"http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="loginForm" type="com.example.web.LoginForm" />
    </form-beans>
    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/TenRetrieveUser" type="com.example.model.UserSignupAction" name="loginForm" scope="session" validate="true" input="/My_APP/signup.jsp">
        <forward name="addLocation" path="/MY_APP/addLocation.jsp" />
        </action>
    </action-mappings>
    <message-resources parameter="ApplicationResources" null="false" />
</struts-config>
```

The only .jar I imported for struts is `struts-core-1.3.10.jar`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to include `all` libraries (JAR files) found in the bundle as Struts 1.x are dependent with other Apache Commons Libraries such as Apache Commons Digester, Apache Commons File Upload, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You only used struts-core-1.3.10.jar
but you need to import some other library because
**org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet** uses commons-beanutils,
commons-logging,commons-digester,commons-chain in source code.
So

- commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- commons-digester-1.8.jar
- commons-chain-1.2.jar

should be imported in your projct.

Here is the download link :: [struts-1.3.10-lib](http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/struts/1.3.10/struts-1.3.10-lib.zip)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you have a web app with the 3.1 version of Servlet api (Java EE7).

I'm not quite sure that it is compatible with Struts 1.3. You should try newer version of Struts or downgrade your Tomcat version and your web.xml version.

On Eclipse, you can see also your project Facets in Project -> Project Facets.

Answer (score 0):

I can see an Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.RuleSet
```

1. First make sure you have `commons-digester-<version>.jar` in your class path.
2. Then extract `commons-digester-<version>.jar` file and check if `RuleSet.class` exists under path: `/org/apache/commons/digester/`.